# Instance method requires that 'classname' conform to 'Decodable'

Tags: swift, codable, decodable

I'm trying to decode a JSON response as a custom type, that I believe conforms to Decodable.

These are the codable structs that I am using

```swift
struct ResultSet: Codable {
    var name: String
    var headers: [String]
    var rowSet: [String]
}

struct Scoreboard: Codable {
    var resultSets: [ResultSet]
}
```

And this is the code I'm using to get the JSON from the response

```swift
func loadNbaScoreboardData<Scoreboard>() -> Scoreboard {
    
    //var data1: Data
    
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    let formattedDate = formatter.string(from: Date())
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboard/?GameDate=\(formattedDate)&LeagueID=00&DayOffset=100")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("stats.nba.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "host")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue("stats", forHTTPHeaderField: "x-nba-stats-origin")
    request.setValue("x-nba-stats-origin", forHTTPHeaderField: "Referer")
    
    var retData: Scoreboard
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else{ return }
        
        do {
            let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Scoreboard.self, from: data)
            retData = decodedData
        } catch {
            fatalError(error)
        }
    }.resume()
    
    return retData
}
```

The error I get is `Instance method 'decode(_:from:)' requires that 'Scoreboard' conform to 'Decodable'`

I'm following the dev documentation here too https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:** The Scoreboard struct can't be found. I've added the full method

Comment: Your code should work if it's the whole code of your struct. Do you have another struct with that name? No other hidden code (var for it)? Unrelated, but `fatalError(error.localizedDescription)` should be `fatalError(error)` as in case of error, it will be much more explicit

Comment: Your `struct`s are absolutely fine and I get no error when compiling them. The only cause I can think of is that there is another `Scoreboard` type defined that is not `Decodable`

Comment: Yeah that's the entirety of the struct.

Comment: Ah, it might be down to the class with the data retrieval method not finding the struct, as nagivating to definition doesn't go anywhere. I'll update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `Scoreboard` is a **generic** type (not the concrete type `Scoreboard`). You can fix the error by adding `Codable` conformance

```
func loadNbaScoreboardData<Scoreboard: Codable>() -> Scoreboard {
```

But the code won't work anyway because you cannot return something from an asynchronous task.

I recommend to make the function `async`

```
func loadNbaScoreboardData() async throws -> Scoreboard {
    
    //var data1: Data
    
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    let formattedDate = formatter.string(from: Date())
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboard/?GameDate=\(formattedDate)&LeagueID=00&DayOffset=100")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("stats.nba.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "host")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue("stats", forHTTPHeaderField: "x-nba-stats-origin")
    request.setValue("x-nba-stats-origin", forHTTPHeaderField: "Referer")
    
    let (data, _ ) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(Scoreboard.self, from: data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was the method declaration

It should be

```
func loadNbaScoreboardData() -> Scoreboard {
    // code
}
```